# application on cloud

Tags: cloud

I want to start writing application on cloud. Is there any software or free cloud which I can use?Is there any document which can help me to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud) has a free tier which is good for most basic purposes. If you are proficient in programming and server admin, you should be good to go. I have setup an app on Amazon EC2. It has a basic static website, my blog, and a web application. The technology stack is Apache+JBoss+MySQL+Wordpress.

Comment: Is working with EC2 easy?Do you have any simple example or kind of introduction to it?I am completely new to cloud.

Comment: You will need some time to get used to their framework. But they do have good documentation. But with the free tier, you will have to do a lot of setup yourselves.